# How can I provide a relation extraction data set including tuple for casual inference using name entity recognition by spacy?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, relation-extraction

I have around 7.000 sentences, for which I have done a refined Name-Entity-Recognition (i.e., for specific entities) using SpaCy. Now I want to do relationship extraction (basically causal inference) and I do not know how to use NER to provide training set.

As far as I read there are a different approaches to perform relationship extraction:

- 1) Handwritten patterns
- 2) Supervised machine learning
- 3) Semi-supervised machine learning

Since I want to use supervised machine learning I need training data.

It would be nice if anyone could give me some direction, many thanks. Here is a screen shoot of my data frame, entities are provided by a customised spaCy model. I have access to the syntactic dependencies and part-of-speech tags of each sentence, as given by spaCy:

[image]

Comment: I think I can understand what you want to do, can you please give few examples of the relationships you want do extract? One other thing, if you don't have training data there's no magic, you will have to rely on handwritten rules or some kind of semi-supervised/bootstrapping approach. But please, give some examples of what exactly you want to extract given the information on that dataset.

Comment: thank you again David for your nice responses, Imagine I want to extract "casual relation" like in this sentence: "where the equation caused by the eccentricity is maximum."  I need to extract (equation,caused by,maximum) or (obs1,casual relation,obs2)

Comment: please update then your question accordingly, adding one or more examples, so that others that bump into the question can also get insights on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your dataset is some kind of technical writing, very well structured, so maybe part-of-speech tags are enough to do the extraction you want.

I would recommend you to read this paper, and understand the pos-tags based pattern used [Identifying Relations for Open Information Extraction](http://reverb.cs.washington.edu/emnlp11.pdf)

The piece of code below tags a sent with part-of-speech tags and then looks for sequences that match the called ReVerb pattern.

```
import nltk

verb = "<ADV>*<AUX>*<VBN><IN|PART>*<ADV>*"
word = "<NOUN|ADJ|ADV|DET|ADP>"
preposition = "<ADP|ADJ>"

rel_pattern = "( %s (%s* (%s)+ )? )+ " % (verb, word, preposition)
grammar_long = '''REL_PHRASE: {%s}''' % rel_pattern
reverb_pattern = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar_long)

sent = "where the equation caused by the eccentricity is maximum."
sent_pos_tags = nltk.tag.pos_tag("where the equation caused by the eccentricity is maximum".split())

for x in reverb_pattern.parse(tags):
  if isinstance(x, nltk.Tree) and x.label() == 'REL_PHRASE':
     rel_phrase = " ".join([t[0] for t in x.leaves()])
    print(rel_phrase)
```

There is a bit missing which is to find the closest noun-phrases to right and left of the pattern, but I leave that as an exercise. I also wrote a [blog post](http://www.davidsbatista.net/blog/2017/05/08/ReVerb/) with a more detailed example. I hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your response, especially the lin is very connected. I will go through that. I  put "sent_pos_tags " as "tages" , am I right? but even so it only extracts "caused by'" relation. the last issue. do you think it worth to write above by Spacy?

Comment: @ David Batista would be happy of your valuable comments

Comment: "do you think it worth to write above by spaCy" I don't really understand what you mean by this, please read the paper and try to understand how the extraction of relationship based on pos-tags works, that will clear your mind from lots of confusion.

Comment: thank you very very again,  I meant simply using SpaCy instead of nltk, sURE  I have read it, I will read it again till tomorrow and I hope It can be implemented by spaCy easily on my data, for me, it is very crucial if I can provide training data soon

Comment: I have done! now I have sentences with the verbs as relation, I do not how to proceed!  could you give me some hints! many thanks